# Display 'word' results on seperate line and print first word of sentences which contain the word (Python)

Tags: python

I am having troubles with this question, could anyone help me out?

**Write a program to read in the book.txt, ask the user what the password is, and print out just the first word of all sentences that contain that word, ignoring case. Include all sentences containing the substring, even if it forms part of a word.**

The book.txt file has one sentence per line, and looks like this:

```
The room was dark and dreary.
Beware what lies beneath.
She could barely make out the back wall.
Treasure was piled in the nearest corner, in the dark shadows.
Is this safe, she thought to herself, accidentally stubbing her toe on the dark carpet.
Mister Lieth said it would be cold.
Suddenly, a gust of wind rushed through the door from behind her.
In the wind, the candle struggled, plunging the room into semidarkness.
The thought of the already darkened room having still less light did not appeal to her.
Shivering, she closed the door, wishing she had brought a scarf.
Well and good, she had to focus before it was dark outside.
Black and grey shadows were all she had to believe in.
```

Your program should work like this:

```
Password: dark
the
treasure
is
in
the
well
```

Comment: Is each sentence on a separate line?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get the best help, it is recommended that you share your minimal code which would reproduce the issue to be helped better.

Comment: Yes it is on a seperate line

Comment: Start by describing each step that you need to do to accomplish this task. The description should be in English. Forget about Python and computer programming languages.

Comment: This is a homework question, you have not even attempted to solve it. You must show what you have tried and what exactly you're getting caught up by (i.e. not just the problem in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find_all(password, File_Path):
    password = password.lower()
    with open (File_Path, 'r') as o:
        for line in o:
            if password in line.lower():
                print line[:line.find(' ')]
```

You can use `in`.

```
>>> find_all("dark", File_Path)
The
Treasure
Is
In
The
Well
>>> 


>>> find_all("lie", File_Path)
Beware
Mister
Black
>>>
```